# Determining intersection point in mathematica plot

Tags: plotting, numerics

I plotted the function given in the figure with respect to "z" .I obtained different plots for different distinct values of "t".

Now please can you help how to obtain the intersection point of the straight line and the curves.I.e how to precisely obtain the value of " z" at each intersection point.
Actually I am using mathematica online.So some sorts of code to obtain the intersection point  will be helpfull.

Thank you[image]

Comment: hi there and welcome. you might want to take the tour https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour. also please post code in a format that is easy for copy-paste rather than pictures!

Comment: Given your function f[z,t]  and some function-value you may use FindInstance to get the belonging z-value. E.g.: FindInstance[f[z, 1] == 500, z]

Comment: I run the code but it is not giving any answer.

Comment: Directly post your Mathematica code. Edit your original question and add this code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[z_, t_] = 
 t^(3/2)*Integrate[x^(1/2)/(Exp[x]*z^(-1) - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}] + 
  z/(1 - z)

(* z/(1 - z) + 1/2 Sqrt[π] t^(3/2) PolyLog[3/2, z] *)

pts500 = Table[{z, f[z, t]} /. 
   NSolve[{f[z, t] == 500, 0 < z < 1}, z, Reals][[1]], {t, 10, 50, 10}]

(* {{0.997688, 500.}, {0.996769, 500.}, {0.993754, 500.}, {0.973231, 
  500.}, {0.889759, 500.}} *)

pts700 = Table[{z, f[z, t]} /. 
   NSolve[{f[z, t] == 700, 0 < z < 1}, z, Reals][[1]], {t, 10, 50, 10}]

(* {{0.998417, 700.}, {0.998024, 700.}, {0.997124, 700.}, {0.994246, 
  700.}, {0.976567, 700.}} *)

Plot[Evaluate@Join[{700, 500}, Table[f[z, t], {t, 50, 10, -10}]], {z, 
  0.85, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
   Automatic, Automatic},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Join[{700, 500}, Table[StringForm["f(x, ``)", t], {t, 50, 10, -10}]],
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Blue, Point[pts500],
   Red, Point[pts700]}]
```

[image]